# Permission denied when I try to open the browser and a specific URL from shell

Tags: shell, zsh

I would like to open the browser(no matter which), and browse a specific website, say, `youtube.com`. And I'd like to run it from a `.sh` file.

I have tried:

```
1.python -mwebbrowser http://youtube.com
2.gnome-open "http://www.youtube.com"
3.xdg-open "http://www.youtube.com"
4.open "http://www.youtube.com"
```

All of them got `zsh: permission denied: ./try.sh` error. How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like the `try.sh` file itself is missing executable permissions.  please try doing:

```
chmod a+rx try.sh
```